# OpenGL stable enough for 24/7 running program?

Tags: opengl, freepascal

I am creating a GUI program that will run 24/7. I couldn't find much online on the subject, but is OpenGL stable enough to run 24/7 for weeks on end without leaks, crashes, etc?

Should I have any concerns or anything to look into before delving too deep into using OpenGL?

I know that OpenGL and DirectX are primarily used for games or other programs that aren't used for very long lengths. Hopefully someone here has some experience with this or knowledge on the subject. Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of detail. This will only be doing 2D rendering, and nothing too heavy, what I have now (which will be similar to production) already runs at a stable 900-1000 FPS on my i5 laptop with Radeon 6850m

Comment: 900-1000 FPS? are you serious?!

Comment: Who knows. Driver issues are not uncommon. I'd prepare to have the program re-start itself if needed.

Comment: Harold - it will be capable of this, I just wanted to make sure we aren't having consistant crashes that can't be avoided when using OpenGL for days on end.

Alegen - Yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going into `OpenGL` just for making a `GUI` sounds insane. You should be worried more about what language you use if you are concerned about stuff like memory leaks. Remember that in `C/C++` you manage memory on your own.

Furthermore, do you really need the `GUI` to be running 24/7? If you are making a service sort of application, you might as well leave it in the background and make a second application which provides the `GUI`. These two applications would communicate via soma `IPC` (sockets?). That's how this sort of thing usually works, not having a window open all the time.

In the end, memory leaks are not caused by some graphical library, but more by the programmer writing bad code. The library should be the last in your list of possible reasons for memory leaks/creashes.

Comment: Blender has a fully OpenGL based GUI AFAIK, so it's not all that far fetched (though by no means simple). Although I have a sneaking suspicion it's not what the OP means.

Comment: using a library build on top of OpenGL makes your life a lot easier I agree, but idd OP means raw OpenGL, at least that`s what I understand

Comment: Well, we are rewriting 15+ year old software that is used in prisons, the GUI is what prison guards use etc. We can't use standard form controls and the like, we are going to be cross platform now (Linux, Windows) so OpenGL seemed like a good idea.

We use custom maps, buttons, icons, whatever...It has to look nice, so OpenGL fits the bill (to my knowledge, so far, and in testing).

Our software right now is stable, we are capable, I just wanted to make sure there were no red flags in using OpenGL for so long by itself. I didn't think there would be. Thanks

Comment: "In the end, memory leaks are not caused by some graphical library, but more by the programmer writing bad code." Under normal circumstances, I would agree. However, OpenGL drivers are not the most stable things in the world. There have been memory leaks from drivers in the past. And some probably exist even now.

Comment: Nicol, that was my concern.

Alegen, to add, most of the processing of our software is headless. GUI simply interpets mouse clicks and draws from network messages.

Comment: @IanDubya: Your needs sound like Qt would nicely fit your demands, it's cross plattform offers nice GUI capabilities, also going beyond the typical windows and buttons, and most importantly it offers it's own raster engine making you completely independent of the underlying graphics system. In your case I think of "Qt Quick".

Comment: @datenwolf Agreed, Qt seems a far better fit.  Writing your own OpenGL to essentially replicate what Qt/wxWidgets does anyway just seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

I work for a company that makes (windows based) quality assurance software (machine vision) using Delphi.

The main operator screen shows the camera images at up to 20fps (2 x 10fps) with opengl overlay, and has essentially unbounded uptime (longest uptimes close to an year, longer is hard due to power downs for maintenance). Higher speed cameras have their display rates throttled.

I would avoid integrated video from intel for a while longer though. Since i5 it meets our minimal requirements (non power of 2 textures mostly), but the initial drivers were bad, and while they have improved there are occasional stability and regularity problems still.